# Centering a set of divs?

Tags: css

I am trying to center this JS/jquery/ajax app screen here, such that no matter what size the user's screen is, it will all remain centered.  Right now it is all left-aligned:

http://www.funtrivia.com/html5/indexc.cfm?qid=361927

No matter what I try, it simply does not center.   When I do manage to center the outermost div, all of the inner stuff gets messed up.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Try building yourself a jsfiddle, containing just the basic structure of the site.  If the answer doesn't become obvious to you while you're building that, then post that with your question, helps everyone (including yourself) to visualise the problem!  http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2):

your html is built wrong. everything seems to be positioned absolute and has a left/top defined. It does not help that your body tag has `width: 790px;`

This can be solved with just css. Try removing all the positioning styles from the markup and set #game to be `margin: 0 auto` (the centering trick)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width settings on your body tag

Use "margin: 0 auto" on your gameheader and game divs

and set your gameheader div and game div to use position:relative

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google Search reveals [How to Centre a DIV Block Using CSS](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/center-div-block.shtml)

Use the following **CSS** where `#content` is the `id` of your main div element

```css
#content {
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
}
```

> The technique works because when both margins are set to auto, web browsers are required by the CSS standard to give them equal width.

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/4TuqW/)